# Is the graph of $f(x)=\sin(\frac 1x)$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function in the metric spaces $X,Y$. The graph of $f$ is the set: $$G(f)=\{(x,f(x));x\in X\}$$ And we say that the graph of $f$ is closed, if the set $G(f)$ is closed in $X\times Y$ by product topology.
Now consider the function $f:[-\frac{2}{\pi},\frac{2}{\pi}] \to [-1,1]$ by: $$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sin(\frac1x),  & \text{if $x\ne 0$ } \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$ My question is this: Is the graph of $f$ closed? I think the answer is no. Since if the graph of $f$ is closed, it is bounded in $\mathbb R^2$ and so, should be compact. But if $G(f)$ is compact and the domain of $f$ be compact,  then $f$ is continuous (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220291/continuity-compactness-and-graph/220308#220308)). Clearly $f$ isn't continuous at $x=0$. It's enough to consider the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}$ and $w_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}$. Then, $\lim x_n=\lim w_n =0$ as $n\to \infty$ but $\lim f(w_n)=1$ and  $\lim f(x_n)=0$ as $n\to \infty$.
Is my analysis correct?

Comment: You may see this directly: you have a sequence of points $(w_n,f(w_n))$ that converges to the point $(0,1)$ which is not in $G$.

Comment: Regarding your idea with continuous functions, you are right, see [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/closed-graph-theorem/) by Terence Tao (look for *Theorem 5 (Closed graph theorem (point set topology))*)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thank you for introducing the book and your point in first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.**

You're right the graph $G(f)$ is not closed. The point $(0,1)$ belongs to the complement of $G(f)$ in $\mathbb R^2$. However, you can prove that a sequence of point of the graph converges to $(0,1)$.