# Prove that if $f$ is continuous then we have a compact subset of R^2...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $X$. Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if {$(x,f(x));x\in X$} is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

I need some help and hints on this one.

Comment: One implication is shown here: [If the graph of a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is compact, is $f$ continuous where $A$ is a compact metric space?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231797/if-the-graph-of-a-function-f-a-rightarrow-mathbb-r-is-compact-is-f-conti)

Comment: A more general version (for topological spaces): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143306/f-continuous-iff-operatornamegraphf-is-compact and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134024/compact-hausdorff-space-and-continuity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, then also the map $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2, x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is continuous. Therefore $g(X)=\{(x,f(x))\,:\,x\in X\}$ is compact.

On the other hand, let $g(X)$ be compact and $x_n\rightarrow x$ be a convergent sequence. We show that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. Since the graph is compact, $f(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, i.e. $f(x_{n_j})\rightarrow y$. That is $(x_{n_j}, f(x_{n_j}))\rightarrow (x, y)$. The graph is closed. That is, the limit of every convergent sequence in $g(X)$ is again in $g(X)$. Therefore $(x,y)\in g(X)$, i.e. $y=f(x)$.

Since this is true for *every* convergent subsequence, we showed that $f(x)$ is the only accumulation point of $f(x_n)$, i.e. $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

This is also known as the [closed graph theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem).

Comment: You wrote: *it is enough to ask, that the graph is closed.*
Isn't $X=[-1,1]$, and $f(x)=\frac1x$, $f(0)=0$ a counterexample? This function is not continuous, but it has closed graph.

Comment: BTW one implication from this question seems to already have answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231797/if-the-graph-of-a-function-f-a-rightarrow-mathbb-r-is-compact-is-f-conti

Comment: Hmm thanks for the help, however i wonder, if a topological space is limit point compact, does this mean that every point of the space is a limit point?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Good point, I edited the proof.

Comment: Could you please explain why we get $y=f(x)$ because the graph is closed?

Comment: @George, edited.